# Too many open files when testing a URLs list status in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I am running a code that works perfect until the dataset becomes large. It tests URLs status and inserts a new variable in the data with the status code returned by the server.

I'm not providing data to test because it works well with at least 1,000 observations. The dataset, however, has more than 5,000. In the future, the same script would need to check larger datasets (over 60,000 observations).

The code, written with a huge help received [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77559032/check-the-status-of-a-list-of-website-ignoring-errors-in-r/77559080#comment136733051_77559032), is the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Read the CSV file containing the URLs
# url_list <- read.csv("./file.csv")

## Dummy data to test
url_list <- data.frame(url = paste("https://fakewebsitetotestnumber",
                                   1:10000, ".com",
                                   sep = "")

check_status_code <- function(url) {
    res <- try(
    {
        headers <- curlGetHeaders(url,
                                  verify = FALSE)
        attributes(headers)$status
    }, silent = TRUE)

    if(is(res, "try-error")) {
        return(0L)
    } else {
        return(res)
    }
}

# Check the status code for each URL
status_codes <- sapply(url_list$url, check_status_code)

# Create a new CSV file with the URL and status code
data.frame(URL = url_list$url, status_code = status_codes) %>%
  write.csv("url_status_codes.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

When I run this code with the full data (more than 5,000 rows), I get the following error:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'url_status_codes.csv': Too many open files
```

If I delete rows from 1,001 to the end and re-run the code, everything works fine. Therefore, the problem is related to dataset size.

I found a possible explanation [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751538/loop-url-r-too-many-open-files), but I don't believe there is any unnecessary steps in this script. At least, I don't find a way to make it simpler.

Given the error message mentions the `ifelse` conditional,  I tried substituting the `if()` function with `if_else()` too, but it doesn't work well.

How can I have this working for arbitrary long datasets?

NOTE: with the dummy data provided for testing, the result expected is no errors and `0` for all records in the `url` variable.

EDIT: I also tried modifying the approach and doing the requests record by record, one by one, with a loop using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Read the CSV file containing the URLs
# url_list <- read.csv("./file.csv")

## Dummy data to test
url_list <- data.frame(url = paste("https://fakewebsitetotestnumber",
                                   1:10000, ".com",
                                   sep = "")

check_status_code <- function(url) {
    res <- try(
    {
        headers <- curlGetHeaders(url,
                                  verify = FALSE)
        attributes(headers)$status
    }, silent = TRUE)

    if(is(res, "try-error")) {
        return(0L)
    } else {
        return(res)
    }
}

# Length of the new vector
l <- nrow(url_list)

## Create an empty vector that will be filled in with the codes
codes <- vector(length = l,
                mode = "double")

for(i in 1:l) {
    codes[i] <- check_status_code(url_list$url[i])
}

# Create the data frame
status_codes <- data.frame(url = url_list$url,
                           code = codes)

# Create a new CSV file with the URL and status code
data.frame(URL = url_list$url, status_code = status_codes) %>%
  write.csv("url_status_codes.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

But the problem persists, meaning that the connections are kept open until the session ends, so I need a way to close the connections or use another method to get these server codes.

Comment: The error message states that there are too many open file handles, which probably indicates that URL connections are opened by `curlGetHeaders()` aren't being closed, and therefore R runs out of file handles by the time it reaches `write.csv()`. Need to do more research to determine how to close the file handles... Note that maximum file handles vary by operating system.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find a way to force `curlGetHeaders()` to close the connections or passing a curl command, so I am exploring splitting the dataset in several parts before applying the function with `split()`.

Comment: Added new approach tried without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Some websites could be unresponsive, so the `GET()` call does not get an answer nor an error, and the routine is waiting forever. Adding a `timeout(5)` parametre, code gives up after 5 seconds if there's no answer.

Also, the `pbsapply()` function from the *pbapply* package does the same as `sapply()`, but adding a progress bar, and that's really useful when there are long lists of URLs to check (tested in 37k+).

Finally, after many tries with different approaches, the following code worked well. I changed the `curlGetHeaders()` function with `GET()` from the `httr` package.

The code is also slightly simpler as well:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(pbapply)

# Read the CSV file containing the URLs
# url_list <- read.csv("./file.csv")

## Dummy data to test
url_list <- data.frame(url = paste("https://fakewebsitetotestnumber",
                                   1:10000, ".com",
                                   sep = "")

check_status_code <- function(url) {

    ## Retrieve headers from the server and check the status using
    ## try() to handle the expected errors (blanks, fake urls, etc.).
    results <- try(
    {
        GET(url, timeout(5))$status
    }, silent = TRUE)

    ## write zeroes if the result is an error, and the code in case is
    ## not an error
    if(is(results, "try-error")) {
        return(0L)
    } else {
        return(results)
    }
}


# Check the status code for each URL
status_codes <- pbsapply(url_list$url, check_status_code)

# Create a new CSV file with the URL and status code
data.frame(URL = url_list$url, status_code = status_codes) %>%
  write.csv("url_status_codes.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Tested with a real dataset containing more than 37,500 URLs and it works.